# For loop list of tibbles R

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to create a list of random tibbles using a for loop. I have a large data set where I will need to apply functions to lists of tibbles and create lists of tibbles as the outputs. I understand there might be better ways to do this and would also appreciate hearing those but am trying to wrap my head around how for loops work.

I can create a list of random tibbles with each tibble in the list named:

```
tibble_random1 <- tibble(Number = sample((1:100), 10, replace = TRUE),
                           Letter = sample((LETTERS), 10, replace = TRUE),
                           Logical = sample(c("True", "False"), 10, replace = TRUE))

tibble_random2 <- tibble(Number = sample((1:100), 10, replace = TRUE),
                           Letter = sample((LETTERS), 10, replace = TRUE),
                           Logical = sample(c("True", "False"), 10, replace = TRUE))

tibble_random3 <- tibble(Number = sample((1:100), 10, replace = TRUE),
                           Letter = sample((LETTERS), 10, replace = TRUE),
                           Logical = sample(c("True", "False"), 10, replace = TRUE))

tibble_random <- list(tibble1 = tibble_random1,
                      tibble2 = tibble_random2, 
                      tibble3 = tibble_random3)
```

I cannot figure out how to do this with a for loop or if a for loop is completely inappropriate for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise a list and fill 1 tibble in every iteration using `for` loop.

```
tibble_random <- vector('list', 3)

for(i in seq_along(tibble_random)) {
  tibble_random[[i]] <- tibble(Number = sample((1:100), 10, replace = TRUE),
                               Letter = sample((LETTERS), 10, replace = TRUE),
                               Logical = sample(c("True", "False"), 10, replace = TRUE))
}
```

You can also use `replicate` or `lapply` to do this without `for` loop.

```
tibble_random <- replicate(3, tibble(Number = sample((1:100), 10, replace = TRUE),
                    Letter = sample((LETTERS), 10, replace = TRUE),
                    Logical = sample(c("True", "False"), 10, replace = TRUE)), simplify = FALSE)
```

To assign the names of the list you can use :

```
names(tibble_random) <- paste0('tibble', seq_along(tibble_random))
```

Comment: Thank you. I knew it would be something simple I wasn't doing. I had tried replicate but missed the simplify argument and so it wasn't working and for the for loop I was not doing seq_along.